# Search pattern in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to create a script such that it checks the conditions:

1. Port string should be present in the file and if yes then it's value should be 20000.
2. The file should have a mention of sslkey, sslCert, ssl_cipher (The values against these strings/keys can be anything).

The attempt was made:

```
$ awk '/port|sslKey|sslCert|ssl_cipher/ {print $2,$3}' pkg.conf
port 20000
sslKey /usr/product/plat/etc/ssl/server.pem
sslCert /usr/product/plat/etc/ssl/server.cert
ssl_cipher ECDH+AES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES:RSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DES
```

The problem with the above command is even if one of the strings 'port|sslKey|sslCert|ssl_cipher' is missing even then it runs.

Could this be achieved using only a few lines of awk.

If any of the string/condition is missing then the output should display that condition and also the conditions those are met.

Comment: Not at all clear, please mention 2 simple thins, 1st- Sample of Input_file 2nd- Sample of expected output and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Your details in questions here are input examples:

Correct:

```
$ cat pkg.conf
port 20000
sslKey /usr/product/plat/etc/ssl/server.pem
sslCert /usr/product/plat/etc/ssl/server.cert
ssl_cipher ECDH+AES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES:RSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DES
```

Wrong (port 18000 and missing sslCert):

```
$ cat pkg_wrong.conf
port 18000
sslKey /usr/product/plat/etc/ssl/server.pem
ssl_cipher ECDH+AES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES:RSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DES
```

**AWK solution:**

Correct pkg.conf. Returns 0 and outputs nothing:

```
$ awk '
/^port [0-9]+$/ { if ( $2 == 20000 ) isport=1; port=$2; }
/^sslKey .+$/ { issslKey=1; sslKey=$2; }
/^sslCert .+$/ { issslCert=1; sslCert=$2; }
/^ssl_cipher .+$/ { isssl_cipher=1; ssl_cipher=$2; }
END { if (isport && issslKey && issslCert && isssl_cipher) exit(0);
      else { print("port " port); print("sslKey " sslKey); print("sslCert " sslCert); print("ssl_cipher " ssl_cipher); exit(1); }
    }
' pkg.conf
```

Wrong pkg_wrong.conf (port 18000 and missing sslCert):

```
$ awk '
/^port [0-9]+$/ { if ( $2 == 20000 ) isport=1; port=$2; }
/^sslKey .+$/ { issslKey=1; sslKey=$2; }
/^sslCert .+$/ { issslCert=1; sslCert=$2; }
/^ssl_cipher .+$/ { isssl_cipher=1; ssl_cipher=$2; }
END { if (isport && issslKey && issslCert && isssl_cipher) exit(0);
      else { print("port " port); print("sslKey " sslKey); print("sslCert " sslCert); print("ssl_cipher " ssl_cipher); exit(1); }
    }
' pkg_wrong.conf
port 18000
sslKey /usr/product/plat/etc/ssl/server.pem
sslCert
ssl_cipher ECDH+AES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES:RSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DES
```

Comment: if port is not equal to 20000 and if any of the four strings port|sslKey|sslCert|ssl_cipher not found then it should show an error like echo -e "Port is 18000 , recommended is 20000 and sslCert is not found in the conf file \n"

Comment: You can add into code those detailed conditions or exactly specify in question next time.